# Portable version of KDE's Dolphin file manager

Tags: portability, kde-plasma, portable-applications, appimage

Is there a portable version of KDE's **Dolphin** file manager, i.e. a version that can be stored on a USB stick, for example, and run on arbitrary Linux operating systems?

So far the only thing I could find was a 3-year-old **AppImage** in a [non-official GitHub repo](https://github.com/appimage-packages/dolphin).

Does anybody know where to get an official, up-to-date portable version, or where to find potential instructions on how to make Dolphin portable?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no official dolphin AppImage but you can create one using appimage-builder. Check https://appimage-builder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/examples.html#qt-kde-application-kcalc it contains a recipe for a KCalc which can be modified to bundle Dolphin.

Also, you should consider requesting this to the Dolphin creators.